# php evaluating multidimensional array from inner array to outer araray

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, recursiveiterator

How do I solve the following problem using PHP RecursiveIteratorIterator?

```
$arr = array(
    "sum"=>array(2,4,6, "multiply" => array(1,3,5) ),
    "multiply"=>array(3,3,3, "sum" => array(2,4,6) ),
);
```

I am expecting the following answers

```
(2 + 4 + 6 + ( 1 * 3 * 5) ) = 27; 
(3 * 3 * 3 * (2 + 4 + 6)) = 324;
```

Partial code so far..

```
   $calc = new ArrayObject($arr);
   $MRI = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new      MyRecursiveIterator($calc), 1);
   foreach ($MRI as $key=>$value) {
   echo " Current Depth: ". $MRI->getDepth() . "\n"; 
   echo $key . " : " . $value . "\n";
   $currentDepth = $MRI->getDepth();
   for ($subDepth = $currentDepth; $subDepth >= 0; $subDepth--)
   { echo "sub Depth: ". $subDepth . "\n"; 
   $subIterator = $MRI->getSubIterator($subDepth);
   // var_dump($subIterator); } }
```

Comment: Please show us your progress so far.

Comment: Spent good amount of time , not able to figure it out. I am still trying

Comment: I'm quite sure Scuzzy wants you to show the code you have tried. Not just saying that you have tried.

Comment: Partial code so far..

Comment: Partial code..

$calc = new ArrayObject($arr);
$MRI = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new MyRecursiveIterator($calc), 1);
foreach ($MRI as $key=>$value) {
    echo " Current Depth: ".  $MRI->getDepth() . "\n"; ;
    echo $key . " : " . $value . "\n";
    $currentDepth = $MRI->getDepth();

    for ($subDepth = $currentDepth; $subDepth >= 0; $subDepth--) {
        echo "sub Depth: ".  $subDepth . "\n"; ;
        $subIterator = $MRI->getSubIterator($subDepth);
       // var_dump($subIterator);

    }

}

Comment: Update the above code in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this, do the calculation from the innermost of the array. Check the **[demo](https://eval.in/918073)**.

```
<?php
function f(&$array)
{
    foreach($array as $k => &$v)
    {
        if(is_array($v))
        {
            if(count($v) == count($v, 1))
            {
                unset($array[$k]);
                if($k == 'sum')
                {
                    $v =  array_sum($v);
                    $array[] = $v;

                }elseif($k == 'multiply'){
                    $v = array_product($v);
                    $array[] = $v;
                }else{

                    foreach($v as $vv)
                        $array[] = $vv;
                }
            }else
                f($v);
        }
    }
}

while(count($array) != count($array, 1))
{
    f($array);
}

print_r($array);
```

**Note：**

[traverse array from outer to inner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47708304/6521116)
[traverse array from inner to outer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47666851/6521116)

Comment: Thank you very much. I am using php version 5.4 , would the above code change for old version?

Comment: Also, will this work for deeper level of arrays? For example: $arr = array("sum"=>array(2,4,6, "multiply" => array(1,3, "sum" => array(1,5,6,"multiply"=>array(2,2,2, "sum" => array(4,4,4))))),"multiply"=>array(3,3,3, "sum" => array(2,4,6)));

Comment: Kris, Evaluation stops at the most deepest level. I tried with the following array, it does not work.     $arr = array(
    "sum"=>array(2,4,6, "multiply" => array(1,3,5, "sum" =>array(1,2)) ),
    "multiply"=>array(3,3,3, "sum" => array(2,4,6) ),
);   Do you have any suggestions

Comment: @subra check it now.

Comment: Works great. Wonderful. Thank you.

Comment: Kris,  I had a situation where inner array has numeric key.  I wonder how to approach the problem in this scenario?                                                $arr = array(
 "sum"=>array(2,4,6, 3 => array("multiply" => array(1,3,5)) ,
 "multiply"=>array(3,3,3, 3 => array("sum" => array(2,4,6)) ),
);

Comment: That is simply amazing.

Answer (score 0):

Simple and easy solution :-

```
$arr = array("sum"=>array(2,4,6, "multiply" => array(1,3,5) ),"multiply"=>array(3,3,3, "sum" => array(2,4,6)));
    foreach($arr as $key => $newarr){
        if($key =="sum"){
            $sum = array_sum($newarr);
            $product = array_product($newarr['multiply']);
            $finalarray[$key] = $sum+$product;
        }elseif($key =="multiply") {
            $product = array_product($newarr);
            $sum = array_sum($newarr['sum']);
            $finalarray[$key] = $sum*$product;
        }
    }
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($finalarray);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you kunal. It works. Just curious, would it work deeper levels of arrays ? for example, $arr = array("sum"=>array(2,4,6, "multiply" => array(1,3, "sum" => array(1,5)) ),"multiply"=>array(3,3,3, "sum" => array(2,4,6)));

Comment: according to your structure of array it will work definately :) @subra

Comment: $arr = array("sum"=>array(2,4,6, "multiply" => array(1,3, "sum" => array(1,5,6,"multiply"=>array(2,2,2, "sum" => array(4,4,4))))),"multiply"=>array(3,3,3, "sum" => array(2,4,6))); I tried with this array. It does not work. May be I need to use recursive loops